# How to unit test string value in an object class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to make a unit test for an object class that holds values in it with get/sets.

I understand how you would test a number calculation.

But how do you test get/sets where there is no methods to test like x+y?

This is the class I need to test:

```cs
public class Train
{
    //Variables to hold each Trains details. Using different data types for specific entrys when necessary.
    private string _trainID;
    private string _departure;
    private string _destination;
    private string _type;
    private string _interStop;
    private TimeSpan _departureTime;
    private string _departureDay;
    private bool _sleeperBerth;
    private bool _firstClass;

    //Get/Set for setting Train ID value.
    public string TrainID
    {
        get { return _trainID; }
        set { _trainID = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting departure value.
    public string Departure
    {
        get { return _departure; }
        set { _departure = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting destination value.
    public string Destination
    {
        get { return _destination; }
        set { _destination = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting type value.
    public string Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set { _type = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting Intermediate Stop value.
    public string IntermediateStop
    {
        get { return _interStop; }
        set { _interStop = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting Departure Time value.
    public TimeSpan DepartureTime
    {
        get { return _departureTime; }
        set { _departureTime = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting Departure Day value.
    public string DepartureDay
    {
        get { return _departureDay; }
        set { _departureDay = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting  Sleeper Berth value.
    public bool SleeperBerth
    {
        get { return _sleeperBerth; }
        set { _sleeperBerth = value; }
    }

    //Get/Set for setting First Class value.
    public bool FirstClass
    {
                get { return _firstClass; }
        set { _firstClass = value; }
    }
}
```

I have also made up some kind of unit test that I think is right but it just fails. Can someone give me insight as to how I would do this?

This is the test I have made up (is it really as simple and easy as that?):

```cs
namespace TrainTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestTrainID()
        {
            Train train = new Train();

            string id = "1S45";

            train.TrainID = "1S45";

            Assert.AreEqual(id, train.TrainID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a "real world" application there is no need for any of this - you can just use auto-implemented properties without unit testing. Your professor is likely using this as a teaching exercise to get you used to unit testing and also probably as an opportunity to teach you what the compiler does with auto-implemented properties. If by the next class he/she hasn't explained what auto-implemented properties are and what the compiler does with them, you should ask. Once you and your class understand them, there is no need for you to keep writing 100 lines of code for what could be 10 lines.

Comment: Fails how? what is the failure message?

Comment: @ESuth Any update on the status of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**You are wasting your time re-inventing the wheel.**

Replace your properties with [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), and, suddenly you don't *need* unit tests for your getters and setters, because the compiler creates all the getter/setter code and ensures it's correct:

```
public class Train
{
    public string TrainID { get; set; }
    public string Departure { get; set; }
    ... etc. ...
}
```

(Since you mentioned that this is a "toy example" intended to get you started with unit tests: Yes, your proposed test is fine.)

Comment: The requirement for unit test does not depend on using automated properties or not. Your statement is false.

Comment: @Kris: I disagree: There is no need to unit test an automated property's setter or getter. The Roslyn developers took care of unit-testing that.

Comment: That is not what I am saying. I am saying there is no need to test a class that has no behavior and/or state changes. You are saying the requirement of having to write unit tests magically disappears when using auto-implemented properties, which is no true.

Comment: @Kris: I fully agree with that. I don't see how it contradicts my answer, though. The original code *had* state changes: The setter of `TrainID` changed that state of the member field `_trainID`.

Comment: With auto-implemented properties there is no difference. They backing fields are generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Kris: Exactly. The difference is that the code to do that is not manually written by the OP (but automatically written by the compiler) and, thus, does not need to be tested (if you trust the compiler, which I would).

Comment: I understand what you are saying believe me. But this is a university project and we were told to unit test this specific class. (which I know seems stupid as its tested without me needing to anyway)

Comment: I have a separate unit test that will test an actual maths calculation. But the only way I can see of testing a get/set. Is to just make a string with a specific value, and then make a train object with the same value in the property required and check the two values are equal

Comment: @ESuth did your professor specifically tell you not to use auto-implemented properties?

Comment: @Kris: You are effectively advocating that **language features** need to be unit tested, which is a patently absurd claim. Code should not second-guess the framework (or language) on which it is built.

Comment: @Flater no I am not.

Comment: @Esuth If your professor gives you a requirement to test your getter/setter, regardless of using auto implemented properties or not, the code you did write and post is exactly what you need. It is that simple.

Comment: @Kris: Besides, if you're not going to trust that automated setters work as intended, how are you ever going to write a unit test that does not rely on the automated getter? Because if the setter can be wrong, the getter can be too, which means that you wouldn't ever be able to trust automated properties no matter how much you test them.

Comment: @Flater: In Kris' defense, I think he rather advocates that the trivial manual getter/setters on the OP's toy example do not need to be tested. I don't subscribe to that in general (it's code which *might* be faulty, *especially* boilerplate code that might be copy/pasted), but I can see that the cost/benefit ratio of unit testing that kind of code is not very good and I would probably not unit test it myself.

Comment: @Flater The OP posts a class containing properties with backing fields. IF there was a constructor setting the backing fields, then yes, it is correct to test if the public properties expose the values set on the backing fields.

Comment: @ESuth: If this is a toy example, I think your proposed unit test is fine. I don't see why it fails, though. Could you add the error message to your question, please?

Comment: @Flater: *"You are saying the requirement of having to write unit tests magically disappears when using auto-implemented properties, which is no true."* I think I see where the misunderstanding lies. I have modified my answer to *"...suddenly you don't need unit tests **for your getters and setters**...". Do you agree now?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax semantics aside, unless there was an actual error in code not shown, as you have mentioned this is a *toy example*, or a typo with the values passed to the test which causes a caparison error, the provided test should pass as written

Most times, structuring the test flow can help avoid simple mistakes when arranging and exercising tests

```
[TestClass]
public class TrainUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Get_TrainID() {
        //Arrange
        string expected = "1S45";
        Train subject = new Train();
        subject.TrainID = expected;

        //Act
        string actual = subject.TrainID;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

The likelihood of the above failing now narrows the problem down the subject under test being at fault.

Reference [Unit test basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score -1):

You should test behavior and state changes caused by behavior. Your class has no behavior and no state changes from behavior. There is nothing to test.

A valid test would be when your class would have a constructor that sets the backing fields and then asserting that the properties expose the values from the backing fields.

A failing tests would then point out an error in your constructor.

So assuming your class has a constructor like (simplified for demonstration purposes only)

```
public class Train {        
    private string _trainID;

    public Train(string id) {
        _trainID = id;
    }

    //Get/Set for setting Train ID value.
    public string TrainID {
        get {
            return _trainID;
        }
        set {
            _trainID = value;
        }
    }
}
```

See the below example of a test that can be done to confirm the constructor behaves as expected.

```cs
public class TrainUnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Get_TrainID()
    {
        //arrange
        var expected = "1S45";
        var subject  = new Train("1S45");

        //act
        string actual = subject.TrainID;

        //assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes @Nkosi but all examples failed to point out the constructor part!

Comment: That is not a problem. I updated your example to include the constructor so the OP has a better idea of what you were explaining.

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate that!